# Entity Framework Creating Tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql

I have had an interesting experience with Entity Framework. I created an interface and concrete class that implements the interface to access my database on a server. I had inadvertently used a table name that does not exist in the database. Upon that issue instead of kicking back an error about the table not existing in the database it had created the table in the database.

Interface code :

```
Task<List<Employees>> GetEmployeesAsync();
Task<Employees> GetEmployeesAsync(Guid Id);
Task<Employees> AddEmployeesAsync(Employees employee);
Task<Employees> UpdateCustomerAsync(Employees employee);
Task DeleteCustomerAsync(Guid employeeId);
```

Concrete code:

```
public Task<List<Employees>> GetEmployeesAsync()
{
    return _context.TblEmployees.ToListAsync();
}

public Task<Employees> GetEmployeesAsync(Guid Id)
{
    return _context.TblEmployees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == Id);
}

public async Task<Employees> UpdateCustomerAsync(Employees employee)
{
    if (!_context.TblEmployees.Local.Any(e => e.Id == employee.Id))
    {
        _context.TblEmployees.Attach(employee);
    }

    _context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return employee;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this, does anyone have any advice on this, and is this problem resolvable?

Comment: if you have other tables that refer to employee, entityframework will create those tables to

Comment: @Alen.Toma So is there any way to create an error handle that will stop entity framework from adding a table?

Comment: Well i do my custom setting in onmodelcreating. i loop throw each System.Type and do some custom work like making custom attributes and so on. so you could add a custom attribute over the property and say [EntityFrameWorkIgnore] then you could do your CustomSetting there.